# Restrict individual notebook access in sagemaker instance

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Are there any options/workarounds for restricting read/write access for specific notebooks in an instance? Something like denying specific users access to specific notebook files. Since IAM facilitates permissions only on an instance-level, creating instances for each user should work but would like to explore other ways that wouldn't require making many instances

Answer (score 0):

It would not be possible because the user in the notebook instance is always "ec2-user" and not the actual one. Have a look at [SageMaker Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/studio/) that allows many ways of sharing notebooks with other users.